# this.sendAction is not working for checkbox

Tags: ember.js, checkbox, components, ember-cli

Why is this.sendAction not working in the below code? I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: this.sendAction is not a function

//components/check-box2
import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Checkbox.extend({
  checkChange: Ember.observer('checked', function () {
    this.sendAction('action', {
        checked: this.get('checked'),
        value: this.get('value')
      });
  })
});
```

this.send() seems to be working

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Checkbox.extend({
  checkChange: Ember.observer('checked', function () {
    this.send('internalAction', this.get('checked'), this.get('value'));
  }),

  actions: {
    internalAction: function (x, y) {
      console.log('calling internal change with value', x, y);
      this.sendAction('action', {
        checked: x,
        value: y
      });
    }
  }
});
```

component is used as below:

```
{{check-box2 checked=true name="namedBox" value="xyz" action="checkCheckbox"}}
```

From what i could gather Ember.Checkbox is extending a component so we should be able to do this.sendAction
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Checkbox.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Ember do you use? Since you tagged the question with `ember-cli` I assume it's 1.13.8 or less. `Ember.Checkbox` extends `Ember.View` in your case: [1.13.10](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.13.10/packages/ember-views/lib/views/checkbox.js). This was changed in 2.0 since they are getting rid views at all.

So you can't use `this.sendAction` on `Ember.View` but you can use `this.controller.send` instead.

Comment: the link i have given at the end says it extends a component.
Btw i use ember-cli 1.13.8 and ember js 1.13.7

Comment: ah damn, you are right it extends views. So in 2.0 is it completely removed or changed to component

Comment: hey kindly do check again, it does extend from ember component.
Whether 2.0 or the one i shared. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.0.1/packages/ember-views/lib/views/checkbox.js#L10 OR https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/checkbox.js.
It does export default EmberComponent.extend, one diff is import EmberComponent from 'ember-views/components/component'; and import EmberComponent from 'ember-views/views/component';

Comment: The first link is for `2.0.1` and the second one is for master branch which is `canary` (unstable) build. But your application, as you mensioned, uses `1.13.7`. Here you can see the code for `1.13.10`: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.13.10/packages/ember-views/lib/views/checkbox.js

Comment: Here's the commit with the change: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/e271685e96f0137e3042a480c33c23896b483acc